Symlink files out of /boot to save space? Just during the update?
I have a dedicated /boot partition. It's VERY small (86–94 MB, depending on whether you listen to df or fdisk). I would increase it (or get rid of it!) but this is a coloc server thousands of miles away, and booting from a livecd is expensive. I'm really hoping to limp along via ssh alone.
I'm trying to update from 20.04 to 22.04, but do-release-upgrade failed with:
The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 56.5 M free 
space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 17.2 M of 
disk space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt 
autoremove' and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in 
/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your 
initramfs. 

Unlike these questions…

Out of disk space - /boot at 100%
How do I free up more space in /boot?
My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room
The upgrade needs a total of 103 M free space on disk '/boot'
Very high /boot space requirement to go from 20.04 to 22.04 preventing upgrade

…I don't have old kernels in my /boot, and I have COMPRESS=xz and MODULES=dep set in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf, and I've rebuilt the initramfs to try and minimize space. I'm just still too short.
So, I'm asking dumb questions:

Can I symlink files in /boot to another partition, permanently? (I may not be phrasing this correctly, but: can the GRUB bootloader handle symlinks to another partition? Is the other partition guaranteed to be mounted in time, or can a retry be mandated?)
They'd be symlinked to another partition on the same physical SSD. Both /boot and the target partition are using ext4:
 $ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,FSAVAIL,MOUNTPOINT /dev/sda
 NAME   FSTYPE FSAVAIL MOUNTPOINT
 sda                   
 ├─sda1 ext4     37.4M /boot
 ├─sda2 swap           [SWAP]
 └─sda3 ext4     24.2G /


If that's not valid, can I do something dangerous like symlink some files just while I'm running do-release-upgrade, and afterwards I'll have new kernel files that I can (hopefully, surely) rely on for a reboot?


I don't reboot this server more than 1–3 times per year. I don't care if it's slow to boot. I do need it to boot reliably, however.
Here's what /boot looks like right now. If there's a way to get more lean, I'm interested to know it.
$ uname -r
5.4.0-193-generic

$ sudo du -sh /boot/*
233K   /boot/config-5.4.0-193-generic
6.7M   /boot/grub
17M    /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-193-generic
12K    /boot/lost+found
179K   /boot/memtest86+.bin
181K   /boot/memtest86+.elf
181K   /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
4.6M   /boot/System.map-5.4.0-193-generic
14M    /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-193-generic

$ df -h /boot
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        86M   42M   38M  53% /boot

$ sudo sfdisk -l -s /dev/sda1 | awk '{print $1 / 1024 "MiB"}' # 1kiB blocks to MiB
94MiB

$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.17


Files in the boot directory /boot that are moved (and then symlinked) to other file-systems may not be available during the boot process, and thus your system may fail to boot, so you're taking a rather big risk..  In your situation I'd likely do away with the separate /boot and then perform release-upgrade etc.. ie. fix your actual space issue (returning to separate /boot later if it achieves something you require)

@guiverc I appreciate your feedback on the danger. That's good to know. If you could elaborate on when the other file systems might or might not be available, and any way to mitigate it, it seems like a good answer. Regarding getting rid of /boot: I agree! But, see the third sentence at the start for why I'm trying to keep it. :)

I can't tell you what file-systems you're using, you'll need to ask the person who installed the system, or someone who maintains it for details. We're limited to details you provide.

@guiverc Ah! Thank you. I will edit the question to include the file systems involved.

I see no safe answer within the constraint you have set (no physical access). Mucking with partitions is inherently unsafe.You cannot safely change mounted partitions. The only safe solution is to NOT release-upgrade. If you still have no solution in seven months, then start paying for Pro.

Do you have any available space on /dev/sda? If so, then you could create a new partition and move /boot to that without needing a Live CD. Otherwise, could you add an additional drive? Same thing would apply where you can move /boot without needing a Live CD.

@mpboden Thanks for brainstorming on some alternatives. I do not have any free space on /dev/sda, and adding an additional drive requires physical access (or paying $200/hr, 1 hr minimum). But good thoughts for a future someone who might have a similar situation.
